# Amazon S3 / Route 53 configuração de roteamento

Tags: amazon-aws

Teria como eu configurar uma rota no `Amazon Route 53 ou/e S3` como eu faço no `nodejs` com `express` ? segue abaixo.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/website/index.html'));
});


app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/login.html'));
});

//Se for qualquer outra rota
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('login.html?group='+req.url.substr(1));
});
```

Resumindo, os direcionamentos que quero seria

```
www.meusite.com.br       -> index.html
www.meusite.com.br/login -> login.html
www.meusite.com.br/abc   -> login.html?group=abc
www.meusite.com.br/aaaa  -> login.html?group=aaaa
```

Eu gostaria de utilizar o `AmazonCloud front + S3` e não estou vendo como rotear dessa forma que faço com o nodejs, tentei ver se conseguia com o `Route 53` mas não conseguir.

Poderia apenas deixar rodando uma aplicação `nodejs` com esse roteamento e direcionando para o `CloudFront` mas não gosto muito dessa ideia, o bom mesmo seria direto pela Amazon

Answer (score 1):

Eu nunca precisei fazer isso mas acredito que seja possível. Eu recomendo olhar [a documentação](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html). 
Algo perto disso aqui pode funcionar:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>login/abc</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyWith>login.html?group=abc</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>      
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>login/aaa</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyWith>login.html?group=aaa</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>login</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyWith>login.html</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Só não acho que dê para fazer isso dinamicamente. Você iria precisar de uma rota para cada grupo, manualmente.

Comment: Isso, não dá para fazer uma rota dinâmica como a gente faz com o express do Nodejs, no caso, acabei desistindo de usar o CloudFront, obrigado pela resposta